# Date Conversion in XSLT is giving an error - not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml from one format to another and i am facing an issue in a DateTime field.
My input/source xml is like this:

```
<field name="Creation Time" value="2016-02-24T00:39:52Z" />
```

And the desired output xml should be like this:

```
<field name="Creation Time" value="14:43:20 on 16-Mar-2016"/>
```

Here is what the XSLT i have written:

```
public string FormatDateTime(string date)
  {
    DateTime dt = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(date,XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
    string converted = XmlConvert.ToString(dt, "HH:mm:ss on dd-MM-yyyy");
    return converted;
  }

<xsl:when test="@name='Creation Time'">              
       <xsl:variable name="var_creationTime" select="cs:FormatDateTime(@value)" />
       <field name="Creation Time" value="{$var_creationTime}" />              
</xsl:when>
```

But i am getting an Error:

The string '03:27:23 on 9-Mar-2016' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Please help me to change the date format.

Comment: Is this Java? What XSLT engine? Is there a schema or DTD? Is the XML parser set to validating? What component is actually issuing the error message? What is "AllXsd"?  So many unanswered questions... make your question also unanswerable in its present state.

Comment: This seems to be a question about `.net`, not about XSLT.

Comment: yes, it is related to .net (c#)